# Is it possible to remove a radio button group set to its default value from the get parameter list?

Tags: html, forms, url, get, radio-button

This question is about getting "nice" short URLs from an input form, even with "pure" HTML, when Javascript is off. It is about a form, that gives the user a few choices, each in the form of radio buttons, but most users will actually alter at most one value from their default settings, or none at all:

```
<form method=get action="form.html">
    setting 1:
    <input type="radio" name="val1" value="default1" checked>&nbsp;default value
    <input type="radio" name="val1" value="alt1">&nbsp;alternative value
    <input type="radio" name="val1" value="other1">&nbsp;other alternative value
    <br>
    setting 2:
    <input type="radio" name="val2" value="default2" checked>&nbsp;default value
    <input type="radio" name="val2" value="alt2">&nbsp;alternative value
    ...
</form>
```

So, when the user submits the form, the URL will look like this:

```
form.html?val1=default1&val2=alt2&val3=default3&val4=default4
```

But I want the URL to look like the following:

```
form.html?val2=alt2
```

I am aware of how to achieve the desired nice URLs with client side javascript. And I am also aware about how to clean up the URL using a server side redirect in case, that javascript is off. But is there also a way to achieve the short and nice URL without javascript and without server redirects, just with plain HTML?

The problem is though, that at least google tends to "play around" with those forms, thus generating new URLs, that get pushed into the backlog of what the google crawler needs to crawl. Because of the number of URLs in the backlog and the frequency, with which the crawler requests URLs, it would be a great help, if google was starting with the final URLs and not requiring that 301 redirect.

My attempts to remove the val1=default1 parameter from the URL without javascript/redirect have failed, though. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="val1" value="" checked>&nbsp;default value
```

still puts "val1=" into the URL. And

```
<input type="radio" name="val1" checked>&nbsp;default value
```

results in "val1=on" in the URL. Apparently, radio buttons have "on" as their default value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use  method ***post***

```
`<form method="post" action="form.html">`
```

<strike>instead of method **get**</strike>

you will get a nice url **form.html** instead of

*form.html?val1=default1&val2=alt2&val3=default3&val4=default4*

but also you will have to change the coding of the page(*form.html* here) that handles form data and does something with it.

Comment: POST means, that none of the parameters gets into the URL, not even those, that the user DID change. As I said, I'd like to have: `form.html?val2=alt2`, and not only `form.html`

Comment: U need javascript for that. Can do with javascript, If you are willing to.